# Given $u,v\in \mathbb{S}^n$, then there exists a orthogonal matrix s.t. $u=O v$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

Is the following intuitive statement true:

> For given $u,v \in \mathbb{S}^n$, there exists a matrix $R\in O(n)$
>   s.t. $u=Rv$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist orthonormal basis $(e_1=u,e_2,...,e_n)$ and $(f_1=v,...,f_n)$ define $A$ by $A(e_i)=f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true. We can take $S^2$ as model. Without loosing generality we can change the basis and get  v e u as:
\begin{equation}
u=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos\varphi_{1}\cos\theta_{1}\\
\cos\varphi_{1}\sin\theta_{1}\\
\sin\varphi_{1}
\end{array}\right),\quad v=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
Then for example we can consider the following rotation R which has determinant $1$ because is triangular and transform $v$ in $u$:
\begin{equation}
R=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\varphi_{1}\cos\theta_{1} & 0 & 0\\
\cos\varphi_{1}\sin\theta_{1} & \left(\cos\varphi_{1}\cos\theta_{1}\right)^{-1} & 0\\
\sin\varphi_{1} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
The $S^n$ is just the same with $n$ coordinates instead of $3$.